# Kendo Grid sorting with complex objects

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with read of data for kendo grid.
The controller throw a exception "Cannot find a public property of primitive type to sort by."

**ViewModel**

```
public class PatientModel : IMapFrom<Patient>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public PersonalDataModel PersonalDataModel { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult EditingPopup_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var source = repository.All<PatientModel>();
    var patients = repository.All<PatientModel>().ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(patients,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DentalSoft.Data.Contracts.Patientes.PatientModel>()
.Name("PatientsGrid")    
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.PersonalDataModel.FirstName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
    columns.Bound(p => p.PersonalDataModel.SecondName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
    columns.Bound(p => p.PersonalDataModel.LastName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
    columns.Bound(p => p.PersonalDataModel.TelephoneNumber).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
    columns.Bound(p => p.PersonalDataModel.HealthStatus).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(200);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("PatientModel"))
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Scrollable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "patients-grid" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
    .Create(create => create.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "Grid"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "Grid"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Grid"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "Grid"))
)
.Selectable()
)
```

The ViewModel will has more 3,4 complex objects.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for this issue I found the [following article](http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/10-01-25/resolving-circular-references-when-binding-the-mvc-grid.aspx):

> Create a new class which will contain only the properties required for
>   databinding the grid (properties mapped to grid columns that is). **If
>   binding to EF make sure you add the key property (OrderID in this
>   case) to the ViewModel even if you are not displaying it in the grid.
>   Otherwise you will end up with NotSupportedException saying “Cannot
>   find primitive type or property to sort by”.**

It looks like this issue occurs because whatever `repository.All<PatientModel>()` is returning is missing some property which is required by Entity Framework (are you using Entity Framework?).

You can also try the following:

```
public ActionResult EditingPopup_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var patients = repository.All<PatientModel>().ToList();
    return Json(patients.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your viewmodel to

```
public class PatientModel : IMapFrom<Patient>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PersonalDataModel PersonalDataModel { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class PatientModel : IMapFrom<Patient>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public PersonalDataModel PersonalDataModel { get; set; }
}
```